# Excel VBA Option Buttons - how do you unselect them?

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to unselect `radio buttons` and I can't figure out how.
My latest attempt looks like this:

```
Sheet1.Shapes("STCT" & strNumbers).ControlFormat.Value = xlOff
```

Where the name of the `radio button` is `STCT04` (or 05, or 06, or... you get the pattern) and the number part of the name is stored in the string variable.
I have also tried this

```
Sheet1.Shapes("STCT" & strNumbers).Value = False
```

no luck. I've googled quite a bit, and in 95% of the cases the commenters suggest one of the two mentioned above, and the question poster always says it worked.
It doesn't for me.

What do I do then?

Edit:
I have a list of options to choose from, each has an assigned Button. I have some 10 options, but the user should sometimes only be able to chose from only 5 of those 10. (That's dependent on other things in my workbook.) In these cases (if an option doesn't apply) i'd like to set either the Button's "value" or "enabled" property to False.
When I do that (change either one of the two properties), that unselects every previously existing selection as well. (As if the macro caller button was clicked.)
I hope that makes sense.

Ex: Let's say option 2 is selected. the decision's not final, but i have that selected. Then something changes and eliminates option 3 from the list of options. When I change one of Button3's two aforementioned properties, option 2 changes to unselected as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Value` property.

*By ActiveX option button:*

```
Dim ole As OLEObject
Set ole = Sheet1.Shapes("STCT" & strNumbers).OLEFormat.Object

Dim op As MSForms.OptionButton
Set op = ole.Object
op.Value = False
```

*By Form option button:*

```
Dim op As OptionButton
Set op = Sheet1.Shapes("STCT" & strNumbers).OLEFormat.Object
op.Value = False
```

Comment: Thanks, that works.
However I have some additional stuff that i'll edit into my original post.

Comment: @metrazol I am glad I could help. The additional stuff should be posted as separate question. At best add a picture or sample data into this new question. And you should add some code which you have so far.